# How to remake this cycle

Tags: c++

here is my code which needs to make a check about a student by his faculty number, and if there is no information to say that ...

```
cout<<"Enter faculty number of the student(8 digits): "<<endl;
cin>>ch;
cout<<"Information about student with number:"<<ch<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(m[i][0]==ch)
        {
            for(j=0;j<4;j++)
                cout<<setprecision(8)<<m[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        else if(m[i][0]!=ch)
        {
            cout<<"No information about this student"<<endl;
        }
    }
```

it works mostly fine, the problem is that if my "n"(number of student typed out of this code) is 3 ... we will have 3 student and the cycle "for" will be made 3 times .. and we type 1 student (actually we are typing 1 faculty number) when i start the program it says whole information about that student and on two new lines it says "No information about this student". 
I cant put the IF check out of that FOR with N because i need to roll the m[i]... thanks

Comment: From what i understand, you want to keep the loop going n times even if there arent n students but not display an error message which you added in case a student does not exist ?

Comment: i need the loop because of the array ... if i have 3 student faculty numbers i need to check them all if they are as the typed one on "ch" ... and yes on your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a few suggestions for this code.

1) Checking `m[i][0] == ch` after locating the entry only makes sense if a student is expected to have multiple entries. I suspect not, in which case you should make the loop break as soon as `m[i][0] == ch`.

2) `cout<<"No information about this student"<<endl;` shouldn't be in the loop because it will print `n - 1` times (if `ch` is indeed a valid ID, `n` times otherwise). Make the related check afterwards.